# Download/List files in GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I managed to get upload working but now I have to get the files to display in a list (filename, date uploaded/created, file type and a download option) I can't find how to get that to work

I know I'm looking for: filename(which can link to view the image and checkboxes to left which you can see in the html below), content type and created date.

HTML:

```
<form action="/download" method="post">
        <table id="downloadFile" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="downloadFileDetails">
                        <tr id="dld">
                            <td id="dld" width="2%"></td>
                            <td id="dld" width="80%">File Name</td>
                            <td id="dld" width="10%">Upload Date</td>
                            <td id="dld" width="8%">Format</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="dld" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center "><input type="checkbox" name="checkFile" >&nbsp</td>
                            <td id="dld">test</td>
                            <td id="dld">test</td>
                            <td id="dld">test</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% for file in file_query %}
                        <tr>
                            <td id="dld" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center "><input type="checkbox" name="checkFile" >&nbsp</td>
                            <td id="dld">{{file.user}}</td>
                            <td id="dld">{{file.blob_key}}</td>
                            <td id="dld">{{file.last_touch}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Download File" name="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Python code:

```
import os

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
import webapp2
import jinja2


jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
  autoescape=True)

#Key to serve as a parent
PARENT_KEY = ndb.Key("Entity", "files_root")

# This datastore model keeps track of which users uploaded which photos.
class UserPhoto(ndb.Model):
user = ndb.StringProperty()
blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
filename = ndb.StringProperty()
#last_touch = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    file_query = UserPhoto.query(ancestor = PARENT_KEY)#.order(-UserPhoto.last_touch)
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
    templateHome = jinja_env.get_template("templates/page.html")
    self.response.out.write(templateHome.render({"file_query": file_query}).format(upload_url))

# [START upload_handler]
class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
def post(self):
    try:
        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        user_photo = UserPhoto(parent = PARENT_KEY,
            user=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
            blob_key=upload.key(),
            filename = upload.filename())
        user_photo.put()


        self.redirect(self.request.referer)

    except:
        self.error(500)
# [END upload_handler]

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
('/upload', PhotoUploadHandler)
#('/view_photo/([^/]+)?', ViewPhotoHandler),
], debug=True)
```

message I get in logs:

```
INFO     2016-05-14 20:54:05,506 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1997
INFO     2016-05-14 20:54:05,525 module.py:787] default: "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2016-05-14 20:54:05,546 module.py:787] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8348
INFO     2016-05-14 20:54:11,806 module.py:787] default: "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're recreating the sample application from [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Complete_sample_application). That example glossed over one important piece of information, which can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers#BlobstoreUploadHandler):

> The get_uploads() method returns a list of BlobInfo objects, one for each uploaded file in the request.

So if you wanted to capture the file name, for example, you would need to do something like this in your upload handler (and adjust your `UserPhoto` model accordingly):

```
upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
user_photo = UserPhoto(
    user=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
    blob_key=upload.key(),
    filename=upload.filename
)
user_photo.put()
```

The `get_uploads` method returns a list of `BlobInfo` objects. Docs on those objects can be found here:

- [google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore#google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo)

Note: I don't have any experience with uploads on AppEngine and this code has not been tested, so it may be off in some of the details. I'm just going by the docs. But I suspect it gets to the underlying issue. If any details need to be changed, let me know.

Comment: Ya, I'm recreating the app, but still after implementing your suggestion and reading up more on the blobsore module I have the same issue where page doesn't run

Comment: @Martin You'll need to clarify your problem. Page doesn't run can mean different things and wasn't how I read your original question. Are you seeing an error either on the page or in the console?

Comment: this is the error I get now, after fixing syntax `INFO     2016-05-14 20:45:14,368 module.py:787] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1997
INFO     2016-05-14 20:45:14,388 module.py:787] default: "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2016-05-14 20:45:14,408 module.py:787] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8348
INFO     2016-05-14 20:45:19,279 module.py:787] default: "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -
`

Comment: and page with message "localhost is not responding" comes up